# How do i auto adjust my item positions in a layout in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

This is my Current Layout

[image]

I'm stuck in this issue for a couple of days now. As you can see in the image above. There are 10 items below those 3 buttons. Ignore the buttons please. 9 items are visible and 1 item is below them. its a `ScrollView`. What i want to do is to position all those 10 items according to each other so when i hide one or more items, the rest positions themselves accordingly. for example if i hide the 3 items from the 3rd row then the item on the 4th row comes into the 3rd row in first column, and if i hide all the items except 1 or two then they should place themselves in a single row next to each other. How can i achieve that. I have tried several layouts, maybe i have missed something but i haven't been able to achieve the auto adjust part with any layout. Any help would be highly appreciated,i just want to know what layout or what can help me to achieve this goal ?

So if i hide 2 items from these 10 items,Then it should look like this.

[This is what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jara9.png)

but if there is only one item then it should look like this.

[If just one item then it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afOzG.png)

Comment: Use Gridview or RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and inflate items dynamically.

Comment: @rajesh Ive tried that but if there is only 1 card in my list then it will show that card at the position of 1st row and 1st column but what i want is that it should move to the center itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  a RecyclerView. You can add and delete views inside RecyclerView with layout animations.It's easy than changing the visibility. please check it(Don't know what's your need)

Comment: Here is the problem with that. If i have only one item in my list. whatever layout manager i use. It will show at the 1st position of that layout accordingly, but what i want is to show that item in the center of my fragment. Hope now you understand what i want to achieve.

Comment: so what is the total number of items. Is it unknown?

Comment: Total items are 10, But i have to show them depending upon which item i need. it can be all 10 or just 1 or any number in between.

Comment: so you can change the spancount to 1 when the listsize is 1, I think that will move the item to the center

Comment: Oh dear . How could i miss that . That worked .. Thanks.